# How to compare each bits of a 32 bits number with another 32 bits number?

Tags: specman, e, cadence

I am thinking compare each bits of a 32 bits number with another 32 bits number.

```
eg.    check that ins.dout_1 == (ins.din1_1 + ins.din2_1)
```

Which dout_1, din1_1 and din2_1 are all unsigned integer of 32 bits.
I want to check for each bits from 12 bit to 7 bit of dout_1 equals to each bits from 12 bit to 7 bit of the result of (ins.din1_1 + ins.din2_1) or not.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the bit-slice operation. For example, to compare bits 12 to 7 of some `x` with bits 12 to 7 of some `y`:

```
check that x[12:7] == y[12:7]
```

Or in your specific example, it could be:

```
check that ins.dout_1[12:7] == (ins.din1_1 + ins.din2_1)[12:7]
```